# How to get data properly using Axios and Redux?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I am displaying all information without problems, but when I try to display an image, it shows nothing shows error either.

Trying to parse price before return it `const priceFloat = (product.price).toFixed(2);` shows I am trying to `Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'toFixed')` and inspecting Redux status `product` is empty, trying to print `console.log(product?.images[0].url);` also get same error but lines above I get `product.ratings` for starsOptions without problems. It's kind of confusing for me.

Whatever on `return` to display `item.url` it shows nothing but inspecting Redux I see all information  (image)

```js
import Carousel from "react-material-ui-carousel";
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from "react-redux";
import { useParams } from "react-router-dom";
import { clearErrors, getProductDetails } from "../../Actions/ProductAction";

export const ProductDetails = () => {
  const { id } = useParams();
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const alert = useAlert();
  const { product, loading, error } = useSelector(
    (state) => state.productDetails
  );
  useEffect(() => {
    if (error) {
      alert.error(error);
      dispatch(clearErrors());
    }
    dispatch(getProductDetails(id));
  }, [dispatch, id, error, alert]);

  const starsOptions = {
    edit: false,
    color: "rgba(20,20,20,0.1)",
    activeColor: "#FAC213",
    size: window.innerWidth < 600 ? 20 : 25,
    value: product.ratings,
    isHalf: true,
  };
  //const priceFloat = (product.price).toFixed(2);
  let reviewText;
  product.numOfReviews == 1
    ? (reviewText = "Reseña")
    : (reviewText = "Reseñas");
  //console.log(product?.images[0].url);
  return (
    <>
      {loading ? (
        <Loader />
      ) : (
        <>
          <div className="ProductDetails">
            <div>
              <Carousel>
                {product.images &&
                  product?.images.map((item, i) => {
                    <img
                      className="CarouselImage"
                      key={item.public_id}
                      src={item.url}
                      alt={`${i} Slide`}
                    />;
                  })}
              </Carousel>
            </div>
```

getProductDetails

```js
export const getProductDetails = (id) => async (dispatch) => {
  try {
    dispatch({ type: PRODUCT_DETAILS_REQUEST });
    const { data } = await axios.get(`/api/v1/product/${id}`);
    dispatch({
      type: PRODUCT_DETAILS_SUCCESS,
      payload: data.product,
    });
  } catch (error) {
    dispatch({
      type: PRODUCT_DETAILS_FAIL,
      payload: error.response.data.message,
    });
  }
};
```

[image: Redux status]

Comment: I think you are missing an import
I don't see getProductDetails function imported from redux reducers

Comment: I have imported getProductDetails, just updated my question including it

Comment: It looks like you need to make your component a bit more robust to handle the initial empty state. Don't use fields like `price` if they aren't present in the state yet.

Comment: @timotgl what do you mean with `more robust` what else should I add?

Comment: You wrote that `product` is empty initially, since you can't access `product.price`.